queued transactions stuck on metamask on connection to anvil ( foundry )
I created and deployed a contract through foundry, setup the front end and stuff using ethers
used anvil to spin up a chain and used the private key given by anvil to import account on metamask. Deployed the contracts on anvil using the key provided. Now, I sent the transactions for login ( assume it to be a function in the contract ) few times, yet they are stuck in queue, even on cancelling them or sending money to speed up transaction, they are still stuck I have restarted pc, anvil etc still they are stuck and just show pending. At this point, 3 of the few accounts anvil provides has this issue.

try setting the block mining time and I think it would work. this issue was also discussed in this thread
